# Can I execute S-Function/C code generated by Simulink Coder in LabVIEW/FPGA?

Tags: model-view-controller, controller, simulink, labview, s-function

I have designed a Model Predictive Controller and now I want to deploy it to real time hardware.

I have NI USB 6363 and NI RIO FPGA Module 9124

I have figured out that I can use Simulink Real-Time with NI DAQ Toolbox to implement MPC real-time using Simulink. But the problem is Simulink is very slow and I don't want to use it.

So, my question is to provide me with some guidelines and resources to understand how can I use the S-Function / C-Code generated by Simulink in the LabVIEW or NI RIO FPGA?

Will it execute faster enough than Simulink Real-Time?

My Controller has following settings:

```
Np = 08

Nc =3

Output Weight = 10
```

No constraints

I tried to figure out any hardware solution but these are expensive. I am MS student and I can't buy any other hardware, I need to utilize everything available in my lab.

I can't but speedgoat, or other hardware associated with simulink.

I am curious to use NI FPGA Module rather than USB 6363 because it is faster.